# Why the execution of a query is very slow using PostGis?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, performance

I'm applying this Query to 8257800 point but it's taking 15 hours and it didn't return a results.

```
SELECT a.gid , b.gid, st_distance(a.geom,b.geom)
FROM shp1 a, shp2 b
where st_intersects(st_difference(st_buffer(a.geom,2000),st_buffer(a.geom,500)),b.geom) and abs(a.value - b.value)>400
```

Is there any suggestions to render this query fast?

Answer (score 2):

Your query looks rather strange. What are you trying to achieve with two buffers around the same point?

You can replace `ST_Distance` with [operator](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/geometry_distance_centroid.html), but still we have to overthink the buffer thing.

Could you specify your goal a little?

PS: Did you build spatial index?

UPDATE:

I would try

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        a.gid,
        b.gid,
        a.geom <-> b.geom distance
    FROM 
        shp1 a, shp2 b
    WHERE
        abs(a.value - b.value) > 400 AND
        ST_DWithin(a.geom, b.geom, 2000)
    ) sq
WHERE
    distance > 500;
```

Comment: i'm trying to generate a circle ring with the two buffers. My goal is returning all points wish intersects with the buffer ring of a point ans the conditions are : 500<distance<2000 and the altitude difference is upper than 400 meters

Comment: my answer updated

Comment: thanks for your answer but the distance column does not exist, i want calculate and return it

Comment: distance is not a column, it is just an alias for a.geom <-> b.geom. Answer update - column alias from having clause removed.

Comment: If it works as expected, please mark the answer as correct. Thanks.

Comment: I did some tests with two layers (4M and 800K rows). It took 1060545,590 ms to write the output of 3.3G to a file. However, I had to adjust my swap space as postgresql was running out of memory. And I am running on SSD hard drive.

Answer (score 2):

Go with steps:
-Create spatial indexes for your tables.

-Create Buffers

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW b1 as 
SELECT ST_Buffer(the_geom,500) as the_geom, attributes, fid 
FROM stores;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW b2 as 
SELECT ST_Buffer(the_geom,2000) as the_geom, attributes, fid 
FROM stores;
```

(I am not sure, but maybe you should reduce here you 8 million point to less whith a materialized view like this:

```
select a.point_attributes
from b2 b, spoints a
where st_within(a.the_geom, b.the_geom)
```

)

-Create ring view r2:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW r2 as 
SELECT ff.fid, ff.attributes, ST_Difference(ff.the_geom, g.the_geom) as new_geom  
FROM b2 ff
JOIN b1 g ON (g.fid= ff.fid)
GROUP BY ff.fid, ff.attrubets, g.the_geom, ff.the_geom;
```

-Select those rings where the altitude is bigger than 400 meters.

-And the slow bit the intersection:

```
SELECT ff.fid, ff.attributes FROM r2 ff
JOIN points_table g ON ST_Intersects(g.geom, ff.the_geom)
GROUP BY ff.fid, ff.attributes, ff.the_geom;
```

Comment: thanks a lot, you answer looks like great but please what do you mean by 'ff' and 'g' ?

Comment: ff is just the r2. If you have a long table name like "myspatialtable" you can use shortnames (in this case I used ff because that was in my original query)

Comment: okey man, it's an alias thakns a lot